# Unable to locate elements using nightwatch.js

Tags: nightwatch.js

This is the javascript description of username field on web page which I need to automate.

```
<input style="appearance:textfield;padding:0;position:relative;width:100%;border:none;outline:none;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);color:#FFF;cursor:inherit;font:inherit;-webkit-opacity:1;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);height:100%;box-sizing:border-box;margin-top:14px;mui-prepared:;" value="" id="undefined-EnteryourUsername-Username-47349" data-reactid=".0.1.1.$=10.1.1.2.2" type="text">
```

**The code snippet that i am using to pass value in this input field is :**

```
module.exports ={
    'login to optimdemo site' : function (browser) {
        browser
            .url('https://optimdemo.com/')
            .waitForElementPresent('title', 15000)
            .assert.title('Actiontec Optim')
            .setValue('input[type=text]', 'abc@gmail.com')
            .verify.visible('[type=submit]')                 
            .end();    
    }
};
```

But this is not working also when I am trying to verify that submit button is present or not it gives me the following error :

**Testing if element <[type=submit]> is visible. Element could not be located.  - expected "true" but got: "null"**

Any help on this will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have also used the following code but it didnt worked `.useXpath().setValue("//*[@type='text']", 'abc@gmail.com')`

Comment: does it work if you use the `id` instead? `browser.setValue('#undefined-EnteryourUsername-Username-47349', 'abc@gmail.com')`

Comment: @tehbeardedone - no it doesn't work with id as well. the number in id is randomly generated each time by the application.